# IE8 fixed dropdown issue for multiple dropdown boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, wicket

As we all know IE8 will have fixed width dropdown box even the text content is bigger than actual width  of the dropdown box.For this we have fix also.It is working for me for one dropdown box.
In this case it works for wicket:id="Area" select box.
But for rest of the boxes(Item and code boxes ) ,it is not working.Actully here content in Item and Code box will loaded only after selecting items in Area(There is ajax call).
I have given sample of code here.

```
<div class="fieldsColumn" wicket:id="Container">
    <div class="Container">
        <select class="ie8DropdownFix" wicket:id="Area" style="width:12em"></select>--->look here</div>
    <div class="fieldContainer">
        <select class="ie8DropdownFix" wicket:id="Item" style="width:12em"></select>---->look here</div>
    <div class="fieldContainer">
        <select class="ie8DropdownFix" wicket:id="Code" style="width:12em"></select>---->look here</div>
</div>
```

I have been using following fix that i have got after searching here

```
$(".ie8DropdownFix").each(function () {
    el = $(this);

    el.data("origWidth", el.outerWidth()); // IE 8 can haz padding
}).click(function () {

    $(this).css("width", "auto");
})
    .bind("blur change", function () {
    el = $(this);
    alert($(this).val() + "in blur");
    el.css("width", el.data("origWidth"));
});
```

Please help in finding out the problem

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this please?

Comment: @NicolasHenrard Hi ,thank you for taking care of.I have three drop down boxes(area,item,code).If we select one item dropdown box then other box will get loaded.But here if text length of dropdown box is more than width of dropdown box it will cut off the remaing text.For that i have used above fix.It is working for 'Area' drop down box but not for remaing.Please let me know if you need furhter information.

Comment: I understand the problem, but can you put online your code by http://jsfiddle.net/ ? It will be easier to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after adding chain of events one in aonther:
The follwing is the code which helps some body.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

var el;

$(".ie8DropdownFix").each(function() {
el = $(this);
el.data("origWidth", el.outerWidth()) ;// IE 8 can haz padding
}).click(function(){

$(this).css("width", "auto");
})
.bind("blur change ", function(){
el = $(this);
el.css("width", el.data("origWidth"));
var el2;
$(".ie8DropdownFix").each(function(){
el2 = $(this);      
el2.data("origWidth", el2.outerWidth());  
}).click(function(){
 $(this).css("width", "auto");
}).bind("blur change ", function(){
el2= $(this);               
el2.css("width", el2.data("origWidth"));
var el3;
$(".ie8DropdownFix").each(function(){
el3 = $(this);      
el3.data("origWidth", el3.outerWidth());  
}).click(function(){
$(this).css("width", "auto");
}).bind("blur change", function(){
el3= $(this);    
el3.css("width", el3.data("origWidth"));       
});      });    });    });
```